# Laravel 5 - Prevent direct folder/file access from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5

I have a folder in my public directory that contains some pdf files and images. The structure is similar to the one below:

```
-public
 -documents
   -images
    -image1.jpg
    -image2.jpg
   -pdf
     -pdf1.pdf
     -pdf2.pdf
```

I have created a rest web service that gets all the contents in the folder 'documents' and displays them on a page which can only be accessed by logged users.

For e.g a logged user can view 'pdf1.pdf' with the following url:

```
http://localhost:8000/documents/pdf/pdf1.pdf
```

The issue is that if the user is now logged out and try to access that same url directly, he's still able to view the file.

Is there any way by using laravel or htaccess to prevent this when the user is not logged in?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use a route and a controller to serve the files to the browser.. By using it you can use the auth middleware to prevent downloading when not logged in. Also, this way you can block any access to the documents folder in the .htaccess file

Comment: The only thing I do is to call the rest web service that get all the contents in the 'document' folder and displays it using jquery and in my blade template if Auth::Check(), I include the jquery file.

Comment: You can use `chmod` command